# Efecto Llenado CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css3, canvas, svg

Necesito generar un efecto de llenado por CSS, CANVAS o SVG, que se realize sobre la imagen PNG que tengo.

El llenado puede ser horizontal o vertical.
Debe ser sobre la imagen.

**Actual**
[image: Actual]

**Esperado** : El efecto no tiene que ser necesariamente como una "onda", puede ser vertical.
[image: Esperado]

```css
img {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
}

img.filtered {
filter: sepia(120%) hue-rotate(190deg) saturate(1000%) contrast(100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/co367.png" alt=" acío" />

<img class="filtered" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/co367.png" alt="Lleno"/>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código que tienes actualmente? ¿Deberían de llenarse en vertical o con curvas (como en la imagen)?

Comment: Si es posible, pero debes mostrar lo que has intentado, stackoverflow no es para resolver las cosas por ti, sino ayudarte

Comment: @FranciscoRomero  Edité el post. El llenado puede ser en vertical o con curvas, solo necesito lograr el efecto, lo que sea lógica porcentual y demás puedo trabajarla una vez obtenido el efecto.

Comment: @DanielPérez Hola Daniel , ¿Cómo estás? , perdón si me malinterpretaste pero mi intención no es que hagan las cosas por mi, simplemente necesito saber como lograr el efecto, una vez obtenido esto, puedo manejarlo e investigar más en detalle.
 Ya edité con lo más cercano que encontré pero no creo que sea la solución, estoy lejos del resultado esperado, es por eso que recurrí a Stackoverflow, de igual manera gracias!.

Comment: @nawelittle , gracias por updatear el post, lo siento si mi comentario puede parecer un poco troll :( , realmente no es mi intencion. De todas formas gracias por no enfadarte, todo es para ayudarnos mutuamente y poder resolver los problemas :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como me dices que puede ser horizontal, puedes usar el pseudo-elemento **::before** en el contenedor de la imagen, situarlo debajo de la imagen, lo posicionas abajo con un **bottom:0** y la **altura la parametrizas mediante una Css-var, por ejemplo: --altura-liquido: 20%** y con javascript cambias la variable en el style en línea del elemento padre, la variable así:

```
<div class="ancestro" style="--altura-liquido: 30%">
```

Si quieres le puedes dar un pequeño movimiento de rotación al elemento before como de 2 grados, para simular que es un líquido o usando 2 seudoelementos para simular una onda un poco más realista, acá te dejo un pen con un ejemplo:

[Codepen: Simulación de líquidos solo css](https://codepen.io/g3kdigital/pen/GOeBvz?editors=1100)

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

:root{
  /*¿Altura del liquido*/
  --liquid: 10%;
  /*Altura de la onda
  * Siendo 0.5 (cero) el minimo
  * y 0.99 (cero) el maximo*/
  --h-wave: 0.9;
  /*¿Color del borde?*/
  --cl-bd: blue;
  /*¿Color del liquido?*/
  --cl-lq: #6c77ff;
  /*¿Grosor del borde*/
  --bd: 0.4vw;
  /*¿Ancho del contenedor*/
  --w-cnt: 100vw;
  /*¿Cuantas cajas son?*/
  --n-box: 8;
  /*Ancho del contenedor menos el ancho de los bordes del contenedor*/
  --wlessbd: calc(var(--w-cnt) - ( (var(--bd) * 2) ) );
  /*¿Medida automatica de las cajas?*/
  --s-box: calc(  var(--wlessbd) / var(--n-box) );
}

.container {
  width: var(--w-cnt);
  margin: auto;
  border: solid var(--bd) var(--cl-bd);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box{  
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 var(--bd) var(--cl-bd);
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--s-box) ;
  height: var(--s-box) ;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before,
.box::after{
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;  
}

/* para simular el hexagono*/
.box::before{
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  --bd2: calc(var(--bd) * 2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 var(--bd2) var(--cl-bd); 
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.box::after{ 
  --sw1: calc(var(--s-box) / 8);
  --sw2: calc(var(--s-box) / -4);  
  --sw3: calc(var(--s-box) / 3);
  --c-sw: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  left: 3%;
  top: 3%;
  width: 94% ;
  height: 94% ;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 
    inset 2px -2px 6px var(--c-sw),
    inset var(--sw1) var(--sw2) var(--sw3) var(--c-sw); 
  z-index: 1;
}

.container::before,
.container::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--cl-lq);
  height: var(--liquid);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container::before{
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  animation: wave-shrink 3s linear infinite;
}

.container::after{
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: wave-sway 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes wave-shrink{
  50%{ transform: scaleY(var(--h-wave));}
}

@keyframes wave-sway{
  0%{ transform: translateX(-100%);}
  100%{ transform: translateX(100%);}
}
```

```html
<!--CAMBIA LA VARIABLE LIQUID Y VERÁS-->
<section class="container" style="--liquid: 95%;">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="box"></span>    
    <span class="box"></span>
    <span class="box"></span>    
    <span class="box"></span>
    <span class="box"></span>    
    <span class="box"></span>
    <span class="box"></span>    
    <span class="box"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="box"></span>    
    <span class="box"></span>  
    <span class="box"></span>    
    <span class="box"></span>
    <span class="box"></span>    
    <span class="box"></span>
    <span class="box"></span>    
    <span class="box"></span>  
  </div>
</section>
```

Ahora se me ocurren dos variantes a partir de lo anterior:

**1)** En vez de usar un color plano para el líquido, uses un gif para el fondo que simule la ondulación.

**2)** Otra cosa que puedes hacer es simular el agua mediante canvas, como aquí: [agua canvas 1 codepen](https://codepen.io/artzub/pen/OmaroM?editors=0010) y aquí: [agua canvas 2 codepen](https://codepen.io/miyovanstenis/pen/BfGeK) o con un svg, pero eso si sobrepasa mi conocimiento.

---

### **Actualización**

No use la imagen de tu ejemplo, porque resulta que tu imagen no es transparente, al no serlo nunca se verán las ondas por "detrás", sin embargo, te pongo un ejemplo de como puedes controlar las variables usando js, en este caso jquery.

En el html, si lo analices solo elimine los span y lo mismo hice en el css, cualquier clase relacionada a estos (con la clase "box") los borre.

Fijate en los comentarios dentro del css, te pongo las propiedades que hacen que un elemento este encima de otro, en este caso es z-index: N; entre más alto sea el número "N" este estará por encima.

Ah y agregue la propiedad mix-blend-mode: mulitply, o modo fusión: multiplicar, que si tienes experiencia usando photoshop, lo que hace es que transparenta los colores entre más claros o saturados sean, en el caso del blanco lo vuelve completamente transparente, por eso lo use, pero no te lo recomiendo, lo mejor es que la imagen que uses, ya sea transparente para que se puedan ver las ondas del agua.

```js
var $porcentaje = "60%" ;
var $colorFondo = "rgb(0,180,200)" ;

var $div = $(".container").css({
      "--liquid": $porcentaje,
      "--cl-lq": $colorFondo
    });
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

:root{
  /*¿Altura del liquido*/
  --liquid: 10%;
  /*Altura de la onda
  * Siendo 0.5 (cero) el minimo
  * y 0.99 (cero) el maximo*/
  --h-wave: 0.9;
  /*¿Color del borde?*/
  --cl-bd: blue;
  /*¿Color del liquido?*/
  --cl-lq: #6c77ff;
  /*¿Grosor del borde*/
  --bd: 0.4vw;
  /*¿Ancho del contenedor*/
  --w-cnt: 100vw;
}

.container {
  width: var(--w-cnt);
  margin: auto;
  border: solid var(--bd) var(--cl-bd);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container img{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2; /*para que la imagen este por encima*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /*La imagen no es transparente, 
  entonces aunque este adelante de la onda
  igual no se verá, por eso uso el modo
  de fusión "multiply", que hace que los colores
  entre más claros sean, más los transparenta*/
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  /*LO mejor es que la imagen tenga fondo 
  transparente y quites esta propiedad*/
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}


.container::before,
.container::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--cl-lq);
  height: var(--liquid);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1; /*para que la onda este por debajo*/
}

.container::before{
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  animation: wave-shrink 3s linear infinite;
}

.container::after{
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: wave-sway 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes wave-shrink{
  50%{ transform: scaleY(var(--h-wave));}
}

@keyframes wave-sway{
  0%{ transform: translateX(-100%);}
  100%{ transform: translateX(100%);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/co367.png"/>
</section>
```

Comment: Se puede lograr algo similar al primer ejemplo sobre la imagen?, es decir que sobre la imagen entera final se realice el efecto.

Comment: Claro que si es posible, de hecho puedes quitar los span y añadir un img. En realidad el efecto no depende sino del contenedor.

Comment: Tendrás un ejemplo rápido? nunca utilize variables de css, se me esta complicando lograr el resultado en la imagen. Saludos!

Comment: @nawelittle te puse un ejemplo rápido de como usar las variables css y controlarlas mediante javascript.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!, me sirvio, ahora estoy interiorizandome en el uso de variables css, una última consulta, es mucho trabajo que el llenado sea de izquierda a derecha? es decir como una batería?
https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/57484/screenshots/2071184/charging-battery-animated-gif.gif

Comment: No es difícil hacerlo. Mira este lo hice como en 10 minutos: [bateria cargando - variables css](https://codepen.io/g3kdigital/pen/MrKBpw) solo tienes que poner la variable en el **width** en vez del **height**.